# Image color correction with multiple reference points in python

Tags: python, image-processing, colors

I have a set of images, all containing the same foreground and background. The images were taken with slightly different lightings.
Within each image, I have 3 reference points (let's say a 10x10 region in the image for each reference point). Consider those reference points to be pure white, pure blue, and pure red.

So far, I was able to implement white balancing on all images based on my pure white reference point.

```
def white_balance(image_path, reference_top_left=(42, 82), reference_size=(10, 10)):

    # Read the input image
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)

    # Create the reference 10x10 square for the reference region for white balancing
    reference_region = image[reference_top_left[1]:reference_top_left[1] + reference_size[1],
                             reference_top_left[0]:reference_top_left[0] + reference_size[0]]

    # Calculate the mean RGB values of the reference region - image white baseline value
    mean_reference = np.mean(reference_region, axis=(0, 1))

    # Scaling factors for each channel
    scale_factors = 255.0 / mean_reference

    # Apply white balancing to the entire image by multiplying the image to the scale factor
    balanced_image = cv2.merge([cv2.multiply(image[:, :, i], scale_factors[i]) for i in range(3)])

    # Clip the values to the valid range [0, 255]
    balanced_image = np.clip(balanced_image, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)

    return balanced_image
```

The resultant images are now very similar but some of the foreground RGB values are still not the same. I want to make the color of the images as equal as possible.

Can the other two reference points additionally implemented for color correction? If so, how would the math and implementation for this work?

Comment: consider gamma mapping, and what space you're operating in (linear or compressed)